# Ms Graph RestAPI create team 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

the first try catch works, he is adding the ms graph AD group in  office365.
But the second try catch (converting the group to a Team does not work. I receive an 404 error??
The groupID exists on the server I notice.
Whats going wrong to get an 404?

I did add a secret token on the azure control panel.
The script has the token, appid and tenantid in live time.
also: the tenant has graph roles like group.ReadWriteAll. same for Teams and Directories.

```
Clear-Host

$env:graphApiDemoAppId = ""   # Replace with your Azure AD app id
$env:graphApiDemoAppSecret = ""            # Replace with your Azure AD app secret
$env:tenantId = ""           # Replace with your Azure AD tenant ID

$oauthUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$env:tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Create token request body
$tokenBody = @{
    client_id     = $env:graphApiDemoAppId
    client_secret = $env:graphApiDemoAppSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"    
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

# Retrieve access token
$tokenRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $oauthUri -Method POST -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $tokenBody -UseBasicParsing

# Save access token
$accessToken = ($tokenRequest).access_token

$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
  "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

try 
{
    # Create group request body
    $groupName = "Test_Kenvh16"
    $groupBodyParams = @{
        displayName = $groupName
        description = $groupName
        mailNickName = $groupName
        groupTypes = @("Unified")
        mailEnabled = $true
        securityEnabled = $false
        visibility = "Private"
    }
    $groupBody = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $groupBodyParams
    $newGroup = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups" -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $groupBody
    $groupId = $newGroup.id
    Write-Host "group created:" $groupName "id:" $groupId

    try
    {
        #convert group to team..
        $teamBodyParams = @{
            memberSettings = @{
                allowCreateUpdateChannels = $true
            }
            messagingSettings = @{
                allowUserEditMessages = $true
                allowUserDeleteMessages = $true
            }
            funSettings = @{
                allowGiphy = $true
                giphyContentRating = "strict"
            }
        }
        $teamBody = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $teamBodyParams
        $teamUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + $groupId + "/team"
        $newTeam = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $teamUri -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $teamBody
        $teamId = $newTeam.id
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "createTeam ExceptionMessage:" $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host "createTeam StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
        Write-Host "createTeam StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
    }
} 
catch 
{
    Write-Host "createGroup ExceptionMessage:" $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "createGroup StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "createGroup StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
}
```

Comment: I found some MS info: If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication delays. We recommend that you retry the Create team call three times, with a 10 second delay between calls. Gonna try it today...

Comment: I can confirm. Microsoft needs to replicate objects on servers. So its possible u already can view objects, but they arent really replicated yet, so u cant change properties of them yet. conlusion is that the 404 error was not a script bug, it is replication delay with Microsoft. My solution will be to run script everyday or 4 times a day, and then the next run he will successfully convert the group to a team.

Comment: Yes you're correct @ken. I can observe the same at my end too. I would suggest you to post the answer below. So it can be useful for anyone in the community as well :)